# How to know image type/format by using Image class

Tags: c#, image

I'm working with an image using System.Drawing.Image
and I would like to know if I can get the type of it (ex: gif, jpeg...)

```
Image myImage;
format = myImage.SomethingThatTellsTheImageFormat;
```

or at least, is there some way to say if it's .gif or not

tks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Although I'm not a `C#` user, the API seems to suggest that the [RawFormat](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.image.rawformat.aspx) property is the way to go. The RawFormat property is an [ImageFormat](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.imaging.imageformat.aspx), which you can then compare to the (public) [static properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.imaging.imageformat_properties.aspx) of ImageFormat.

Comment: yes, it's by using the RawFormat property, comparing guid ids 
ex: myImage.RawFormat.Guid == ImageFormat.Gif.Guid =)

Answer (score 2):

Just as little extension to Stephen's answer:
The RawFormat can easily be compared with the public static properties of System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.

Comment: Thanks Florian, I have edited my answer to include your expansion (just to have them both in one answer). Please enjoy this upwards orange arrow.